# Google Play Billing Library 4.0.0 - querySkuDetailsAsync does not retreive all the sku details

Tags: android, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I implemented in-app billing using `com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0` library

The `skuList` I provide contains **8** elements. I get the results only for **7**.
The one that is excluded does exist; so the problem is not about my app missing one product

```
        SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkusList(skuList)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                .build();

        Log.d(C.T4,"SKU list size: " + skuList.size()); // the skuList contains 8 skus (all valid)

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, (billingResult,skuDetailsList) -> {
            Log.d(C.T4,"skuDetailsList size: " + skuDetailsList.size()); // I get the details only for 7 skus
        });
```

Comment: You are setting the `SkuDetailsParams` type to `SUBS`. As you say you have 8 valid SKUs provided by the `skuList` but `querySkuDetailsAsync` will return the `skuDetailsList` only of the `SUBS type`. Is that any chance you have 1 SKU of `INAPP type`?

Comment: No chance. All of them are SUBS. Actually, if I remove any 1 of the 8, it will return the other 7. It's like there is a LIMIT 7 on the query. weird

Comment: Have you found a solution? For some reason I'm always getting one inapp element missing.

Comment: I don't remember what I've done. It works well now. I use the same code with the latest version of the library (com.android.billingclient:billing:5.1.0). However, I will have to refactor the code because I see "querySkuDetailsAsync()" is deprecated now.

Comment: I experience a very similar behaviour some users do not get the existing skus while others do get them. All use modern phones and API versions.